# How to prove these relations for Pauli matrices?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, spinors

I am reading Schwartz's QFT book and I am trying to verify (10.141) and (10.142). σ means Pauli matrix and $ϵ:=−iσ_2$.
How to prove these relations?
$$\sigma^{\mu}_{\alpha\dot{\alpha}}\sigma^{\nu}_{\beta\dot{\beta}}g_{\mu\nu}=2\epsilon_{\alpha\beta}\epsilon_{\dot\alpha\dot\beta} \tag{10.141}$$
$$\epsilon_{\alpha\beta}\epsilon_{\dot\alpha\dot\beta}\sigma^{\mu\alpha\dot{\alpha}}=\sigma^{\mu}_{\beta\dot{\beta}}.\tag{10.142} $$

Comment: What have you tried? What is the problem you are facing? What does the notation mean? What is the epsilon? I can assume that this is a supersymmetry related question, but you should reformulate it so others can also benefit from the discussion.

Comment: I am reading Schwartz's QFT book and I am trying to verify (10.141),(10.142).$\sigma$ means Pauli matrix and $\epsilon:=-i\sigma_2$.

Comment: Start with $\sigma^\mu_{\alpha {\dot \alpha}} \sigma^\nu_{\beta {\dot \beta}} g_{\mu\nu}$. What could this possibly be equal to? All quantities here are Lorentz invariant and therefore so is their product. Now, what Lorentz invariant object do we have which has the required index structure? The only option is $\epsilon_{\alpha\beta} \epsilon_{\dot\alpha\dot\beta}$. So the two must be proportional. You can then fix the proportionality constant by setting $\alpha={\dot \alpha}=1$ and $\beta={\dot \beta}=2$.

Comment: The second equation (as it stands in v1) is simply a _definition_. What you perhaps meant to replace one of the $\sigma^\mu$ with ${\bar \sigma}^\mu$. You can prove this following the derivation described above.

Answer (score 0):

***(10.142):***

For the second relation we will justify the need of covariant components of Weyl-spinors in a similar way as covariant vector components are needed in special relativity (SRT). Remind that in SRT contravariant vector components transform as ($g \equiv (g)_{ik}$ as Minkowski metric tensor):

$$\bar{u}^k = L^k_{\,m} u^m \,(\bar{u}=Lu) \quad  \text{whereas covariant components transform like}\quad \bar{u}_i = L_i^{\, m} u_m \, (\bar{u} = L^{-1 T} u)\quad\text{because of}\quad L_i^{\,m} = g_{ik} L^k_{\,j} g^{jm}$$

The latter relation can be written  in matrix notation:

$L^{-1T}=gLg^{-1}\quad\quad\quad (*)$

$L^i_{\,k}$ are the components of the defining representation, whereas $L_i^{\,m}$ are the components of the contragredient representation. Covariant components would not be necessary if  $g\equiv I_{4x4}$. But that's not the case.

A similar thing occurs to Weyl-spinors (undotted and dotted) ones. To that end we have to study the representation theory of Weyl-spinors.

These transformations are realised by 2x2 matrices $A\in SL(2,\mathbf{C})$:

$\Psi' = A\Psi \quad\quad\text{ or} \quad\quad \Psi'^J = A^J_{\,K} \Psi^K$

As for the vector representation in SRT  a contragredient representation  exists $A\rightarrow A^{-1T}$ in spinor theory. We are going to construct it. To that purpose we need another relationship of Pauli-matrices (check it by direct calculation):

$\sigma_2 \vec{\sigma}\sigma_2^{-1} = -\vec{\sigma}^T$

Then a matrix $A\in SL(2,\mathbf{C})$ can be written in 2 ways ($\vec{\alpha}$ and $\vec{u}$ are the rotation and velocity parameters of the corresponding Lorentz transformation):

$$A=\exp\left(-\frac{i}{2}(\vec{\alpha}-i \vec{u})\vec{\sigma}\right)=\sigma_2\exp\left(\frac{i}{2}(\vec{\alpha}-i\vec{u})\vec{\sigma}^T\right)\sigma_2^{-1} = \sigma_2 A^{-1T} \sigma_2^{-1}$$

or as we will need in the following  according to $\sigma_2 =\sigma_2^{-1}$:

$$A =  \sigma_2^{-1} A^{-1T} \sigma_2\quad \text{respectively}\quad A^{-1T} =  \sigma_2 A \sigma_2^{-1}  $$

Actually this relation shows that the defining and contragredient representations of $SL(2,\mathbf{C})$ are equivalent. Moreover we can observe that $\sigma_2$ respectively $\epsilon$ now assumes the role of the metric tensor $g$ in (*).

We can now define a spinor $\Phi = \epsilon \Psi$ and $\Phi' = \epsilon \Psi'$.
Then the transformation between $\Phi'$ and $\Phi$ is the following (note that $\epsilon = i\sigma_2$):

$$\Phi'=\epsilon \Psi' = \epsilon A\Psi = \epsilon A\epsilon^{-1} \Phi =\sigma_2 A\sigma_2^{-1}\Phi = A^{-1 T}\Phi$$

which then can be written conveniently in covariant components:

$\Phi'_J = A_J^{\,K} \Phi_K \quad\text{with}\quad A_J^{\,K} A^J_{\,L} = \delta^{K}_L$

Therefore $\Phi =\epsilon \Psi$ actually corresponds to $\Phi_J =\epsilon_{JK}\Psi^K$ as $u_i = g_{ik} u^k$ in SRT.
The same conclusion can be drawn for dotted Weyl-spinors: $\Phi_\dot{J}=\epsilon_{\dot{J}\dot{K}} \Psi^{\dot{K}}$.

We could also have used $\sigma_2$ as "metric tensor" in spinor theory. But in order to make this tensor real $\epsilon= i\sigma_2$ is used (it's just convention).

Then the second relation (10.142)

$ \sigma_{\mu\beta\dot{\beta}}:=  \epsilon_{\alpha\beta}\epsilon_{\dot{\alpha}\dot{\beta}}\sigma^{\mu\alpha\dot{\alpha}}$

is just the definition of the covariant components of the $\sigma^{\mu}$ and its relation to its contravariant components.

***(10.141):***

The first relation  can be just be verified by using the definitions of the symbols ($\mu =(0,1,2,3))$: $\sigma^\mu = (I,\vec{\sigma})$ with $I$ as 2x2 identity matrix. The 3 Pauli-matrices fulfill the well-known relations $\sigma_a \sigma_b = \delta_{ab} \cdot I + i\epsilon_{abc}\sigma_c$ with $a,b,c = 1,2,3$. And $$\epsilon := i\sigma_2= \left( \begin{array}{cc} 0  & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{array}\right)$$.